# ionic4 Background GeoLocation

Tags: ionic4

In my ionic project I plan to get the location of the program all the time, regardless of whether it is in the foreground or in the background.

I'm currently using two plug-ins to implement this functionality

- cordova-plugin-background-geolocation
- cordova-plugin-background-mode

But I ran into several problems.

1. When my device is in the background, sometimes it will return the location I need on time, but sometimes it won't.
2. When I'm in a building or a subway, it doesn't return to its position, and then when I'm in the open, it still doesn't return to its position.

   ##start Background Button##

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**background.page.ts**/

    startBackground() {
        const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
          desiredAccuracy: 0,
          stationaryRadius: 1,
          distanceFilter: 1,
          debug: true, 
          stopOnTerminate: false, 
          stopOnStillActivity: true,
          interval: 10000,
          fastestInterval: 5000,
          activitiesInterval: 10000,
          startOnBoot:true
        };

        this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).then(() => {
          this.backgroundGeolocation
            .on(BackgroundGeolocationEvents.location)
            .subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
              console.log(`后台定位数据：${JSON.stringify(location)} --------回传时间：${new Date()}`);
              let backgroundGeoLocation = JSON.stringify(location);
              this.setLocationData(location.longitude, location.latitude, new Date());
            });
        });

        // start recording location
        this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
      }
```

```
  /**app.component.ts**/


    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.statusBar.styleDefault();
          this.splashScreen.hide();
          this.jpush.init();
          this.jpush.setDebugMode(true);

          //cordova-plugin-background-mode
          this.backgroundMode.enable();
          this.backgroundMode.on("activate").subscribe(() => {
            this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
          });

        });
      }
```